# Is $\Delta^2V$  one of the nature's favourite patterns?

Tags: soft-question, physics

I was reading Sawyer's *Prelude to Mathematics*, he says that there's one suposed *nature's favourite pattern* which is:

$$\Delta^2V$$

He also says that this pattern is found in a dozen areas: *conection with gravitation, light,sound, heat, magnetism, electrostatics, electric currents, electromagnetic radiation, waves at the sea, the flight of aeroplanes, vibrations of elastic bodies and the mechanics of the atom.*

So what is this pattern and how does it works?

Comment: Very often problems are spherically symmetric and one wants to have an operator which does not involve to high derivatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably referring to the [Laplace Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), or Laplacian $\triangledown^2$, or $\Delta$. The article I linked to has a fair bit of information.

It is not clear that *Nature* plays favourites. But *physicists* certainly find the Laplacian useful.